# How to show the files of a commit (git show --name-only) using JGit

Tags: git, jgit

I want the same output as given by following command

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only <commitid>
```

by using JGit

Can someone help me out with the step wise procedure of how to proceed?

Comment: There is no notion of a 'package' in git, what exactly do you mean with 'package'?

Comment: With Package I mean the workspace or the mainline. I mean I want to know the commit logs without checking out the code into my repository incase it is possible. Incase it is not, then how?

Comment: What information do you want to obtain from the commit log? I.e. which native git command would you use to obtain this information? What have you tried so far (append code if any to the question)?

Comment: I have tried git show --pretty="format:" --name-only <commitid>  and it lists me the file names that have been changed. I want the same information retrieved through Java Program

Comment: [FileRepositoryBuilder is the right way](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/22/access-git-repository-with-jgit/), but use a **local** repositoy in `setGitDir()`, Use the builder like this: `builder.setGitDir( new File( "/path/to/repo" ) ).setMustExist( true ).build();`

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `RevWalk` to obtain the *tree* of the commit in question and then a `TreeWalk` to iterate over the files contained in that commit.

```java
Repository repo = git.getRepository();
ObjectId commitId = repo.resolve( "<id of commit>" );
RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( repo );
RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit( commitId );
RevTree tree= commit.getTree();
TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk( repo );
treeWalk.addTree( tree );
treeWalk.setRecursive( true );
while( treeWalk.next() ) {
  System.out.println( treeWalk.getPathString() );
}
revWalk.release();
treeWalk.release();
```

Comment: I have added my code. Could you please suggest me changes required. I am trying to connect to the Git URL and retrieve the repository information. Is FileRepositoryBuilder the correct way of accessing or is there any better way to connect to a URL?